# A PictureBox Problem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, picturebox

I have a problem:

I have 3 picture boxes with 3 different images **as in Image**

what can i set to **pictureBox3** so both images look same.....

[image]

**EDITED:** 
I want to move pictureBox3 on pictureBox2,

So there is no Option to merge them to single image

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'll add another example that according to the updated requirement allows for moving image3.
To get it working, put an image with transparency in `Resources\transp.png`
This uses the same image for all three images, but you can simply replace transparentImg for image1 and image2 to suitable images.

Once the demo is started the middle image can be dragged-dropped around the form.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly Image transparentImg; // The transparent image
    private bool isMoving = false;         // true while dragging the image
    private Point movingPicturePosition = new Point(80, 20);   // the position of the moving image
    private Point offset;   // mouse position inside the moving image while dragging
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // 
        // pictureBox1
        // 
        this.pictureBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
        this.pictureBox1.Name = "pictureBox1";
        this.pictureBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(231, 235);
        this.pictureBox1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.pictureBox1.TabStop = false;
        this.pictureBox1.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_Paint);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseDown += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseDown);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseMove += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseMove);
        this.pictureBox1.MouseUp += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.pictureBox1_MouseUp);
        this.Controls.Add(this.pictureBox1);
        transparentImg = Image.FromFile("..\\..\\Resources\\transp.png");
    }

    private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        var g = e.Graphics;
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(transparentImg, new Point(20, 20));      // image1
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(transparentImg, new Point(140, 20));     // image2
        g.DrawImageUnscaled(transparentImg, movingPicturePosition);  // image3
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        var r = new Rectangle(movingPicturePosition, transparentImg.Size);
        if (r.Contains(e.Location))
        {
            isMoving = true;
            offset = new Point(movingPicturePosition.X - e.X, movingPicturePosition.Y - e.Y);
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMoving)
        {
            movingPicturePosition = e.Location;
            movingPicturePosition.Offset(offset);
            pictureBox1.Invalidate();
        }
    }

    private void pictureBox1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMoving = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a lot Albin for your answer, It is working better than what I expected, Great Work!!!

Comment: You'll want to capture the mouse in MouseDown and release capture in MouseUp. This assures that move messages get sent even when the user moves outside your window.

Answer (score 10):

Make sure the image in `pictureBox3` is transparent. Set the `BackColor` to transparent. In code, set the `Parent` property of the `pictureBox3` to be `pictureBox2`. Adjust the `Location` coordinates of `pictureBox3` since they will be relative to the coordinates of `pictureBox2` once you've changed the `Parent`.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox3.Parent = pictureBox2;
        pictureBox3.Location =
            new Point(
                pictureBox3.Location.X
                - pictureBox2.Location.X,
                pictureBox3.Location.Y
                - pictureBox2.Location.Y);

    }
```

In designer you will not see the transparency, but at runtime you will.

**Update**

In the image, the left side shows the designer view, the right side is the runtime version.
[image: Left: Designer view, Right: How it looks at runtime]

**Another update**

I really don't understand how it would be possible that this doesn't work for you. I suppose there must be something we are doing different. I'll describe the exact steps to take to create a working sample. If you follow the exact same steps, I wonder if we'll get the same results or not. Next steps describe what to do and use two images I found on the net.

- Using Visual Studio 2008, create a New Project using template Windows Forms Application. Make sure the project is targeted at the .NET Framework 3.5.
- Set the Size of the Form to 457;483.
- Drag a PictureBox control onto the form. Set its Location to 0;0 and its Size to 449;449.
- Click the ellipsis besides its Image property, click the Import... button and import the image at http://a.dryicons.com/files/graphics_previews/retro_blue_background.jpg (just type the URL in the File name text box and click Open). Then click OK to use the image.
- Drag another PictureBox onto the form, set its Location to 0;0 and its Size to 256;256. Also set its BackColor property to Transparent.
- Using the same method as described above, import image http://www.axdn.com/redist/axiw_i.png which is a transparent image.
- Now place the following code in the form's OnLoad event handler:

  ```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      pictureBox2.Parent = pictureBox1;
  }
  ```

That's it! If I run this program I get a transparent image on top of another image.

Comment: You might think you could also change the location by using `pictureBox3.Location.Offset` but that doesn't work because the `Location` property returns a value, not a reference. If you want to use `Offset` you have to create a variable to hold the `Point`, use `Offset` on that variable and assign it to `pictureBox3.Location`.

Comment: I have already tried this (setting parent property) but its not going to be transparent...

Comment: That's strange. In my case it did work. I've added an image showing the result. Did you notice I said it will _not_ be transparent in the Designer but only at runtime?

Comment: I'm using .NET 3.5 too. I've added the exact steps to take to get it working. Or at least, those steps lead to a working situation on my machine. Maybe the OS has something to do with it too? Anyway, please post back the result you get after following the steps outlined above.

Answer (score 3):

This code will do the trick:

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
{
    g.DrawImage(pictureBox2.Image, 
        (int)((pictureBox1.Image.Width - pictureBox2.Image.Width) / 2),
        (int)((pictureBox1.Image.Height - pictureBox2.Image.Height) / 2));
    g.Save();
    pictureBox1.Refresh();
}
```

It will draw the image from pictureBox2 on the existing image of pictureBox1.

Answer (score 2):

For starters, set the `BackColor` property of PictureBox3 to Transparent. This should work in almost all cases.

You should also use an image with a transparent background instead of white so you do not have the white borders around your purple circle. (Recommended image format: PNG)

---

**Update**
Following the replies I got, it appears setting the `BackColor` to Transparent doesn't work. In that case, it's best you handle the `Paint` event of the PictureBox and do the painting of the new image yourself as [Albin suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/placing-a-picturebox-on-another-picturebox/4144502#4144502).

Comment: i have tried to set backColor to transparent but it not works it gives the color of form..

Comment: Javed is right, setting BackColor to transparent does not make the actual control transparent

Comment: It is transparent, but you see the *form's* pixels.  Stacking effects don't work.  It can be made to work but it is fugly.  Merging the images yourself is far easier.

Answer (score 0):

You might do some hack by overriding OnPaint and stuff, example [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winforms/thread/f43ed61e-6e15-41f8-801d-1e908810eed2/).

But I'd recommend to merge the pictures in pictureBox2 and 3 into a single image before displaying them in a single pictureBox.

Comment: There's a possibility he's writing an app for kids you know... Shape matching and so on.

Comment: @Alex, catching MouseDown and MouseMove with some repainting should take care of that.