# C#, how to make a picture background transparent?

Tags: c#

I have a picturebox with a png in it. Yet even when I set the BackColor to Transparent, it is not transparent. Any ideas what might be wrong? :)

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: The screen shot is of the designer - does this also happen when running the application?

Comment: It looks like there's a gradient in that image. Even if you find the right color for the alpha channel, that gradient will be ugly as sin.

Comment: The PNG does have a transparent background. If I set other colors as BackColor, the color is seen. Therefor the png itself if ok.

Comment: Its a shadow, not a gradient. Looks fine in photoshop. :)

Comment: I think a picture box doesn't support transparent background at all.

Comment: It is *not* transparent, it has a complete gradient to the edge.  From dark-gray to light-gray.  Zoom in to see that.  It can only look good on a background that's the same shade of light-gray.  Anti-aliased images don't work with transparency at all.

Comment: it is transparent, the light gray color is coming from the form background.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have also faced the problem regarding transparent pictures.

you have to Draw it through code.
      See my question  [A PictureBox Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem)

**EDIT:**

In **paint event** (Control containing Background Image)
write this

```
  //If added your image in project's resources get from there OR your Image location
  Image img = yourNamespace.Properties.Resources.yourPicture;   
  e.Graphics.DrawImage(img,50,50,100,100);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your PNG file should also have the transparent background. This is can be done while creating the image(png) files.

Comment: The PNG does have a transparent background. If I set other colors as BackColor, the color is seen. Therefor the png itself if ok.

Comment: I did some searching on it and looks like other guys also faced this problem. Someone suggested using a Panel control instead of PictureBox. Is that an option for you?

Answer (score 2):

You really have to draw it through code. Place a pictureBox on your form, set sizeMode and docking as you like. Then you may fire the following function on the pictureBox's PAINT event:

> ```
>     public void LogoDrawTransparent(PaintEventArgs e)
>     {
>         // Create a Bitmap object from an image file.
>         Image myImg;
>         Bitmap myBitmap;
> ```

```
        try
        {
            myImg = cls_convertImagesByte.GetImageFromByte(newImg);
            myBitmap = new Bitmap(myImg); // @"C:\Temp\imgSwacaa.jpg");  

            // Get the color of a background pixel.
            Color backColor = myBitmap.GetPixel(0, 0); // GetPixel(1, 1); 
            Color backColorGray = Color.Gray;
            Color backColorGrayLight = Color.LightGray;
            Color backColorWhiteSmoke = Color.WhiteSmoke;
            Color backColorWhite = Color.White;
            Color backColorWheat = Color.Wheat;

            // Make backColor transparent for myBitmap.
            myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColor);
                    // OPTIONALLY, you may make any other "suspicious" back color transparent (usually gray, light gray or whitesmoke)
            myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColorGray);
            myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColorGrayLight);
            myBitmap.MakeTransparent(backColorWhiteSmoke);

            // Draw myBitmap to the screen.
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(myBitmap, 0, 0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height); //myBitmap.Width, myBitmap.Height);
        }
        catch
        {
            try { pictureBox1.Image = cls_convertImagesByte.GetImageFromByte(newImg); }
            catch { } //must do something
        }
    }
```

This is my class that is referenced in the above function:

```
    class cls_convertImagesByte
{

    public static Image GetImageFromByte(byte[] byteArrayIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(byteArrayIn);
        Image returnImage = Image.FromStream(ms);
        return returnImage;
    }

    public static byte[] GetByteArrayFromImage(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Thanks. chagbert.

Answer (score 0):

From what I learned I can't do it within a windows form, as it doesn't have layers for the images. So guess will have to make it as WPF. :)

Answer (score 0):

How did you create the background? Is that set by setting the `Form.BackgroundImage`?
If that background (the paper like image) is a container control, the transparency should just work.
However, If you are placing two `PictureBox` objects on top of eachother this doesn't work. The transparent area takes on the color of its parent object. If you have two `PictureBox` objects they both will have the `Form` as their parent. If this is your situation, it can be solved by setting the transparent image's `Parent` property to be the background image.

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        transparentPictureBox.Parent = backgroundPictureBox;
    }
```

When changing the `Parent` property, the `Location` of the `tranparentPictureBox` will become relative to its new parent. You'd have to subtract the x and y coordinates of the background image from the transparent image. See my answer on [A PictureBox Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem/4418023#4418023) for an example with a screen shot.

AFAIK, you can not set the `Parent` in the Designer, only in code. Therefore, the Designer will still *not* show a transparent image, but at runtime it should.

The same problem occurs if you place a transparent `Label` on top of a `PictureBox` object.