# How can I set the background to transparent for my image?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I got into a problem. I downloaded a photo without a background PNG file and I used the image inside the button. And I want to make that photo transparent so I don't have that squares in the button. So I want to set transparent background for the image.

Here's an image:

[image]

Comment: Hi Andrei, I think your transparent image is not actually transparent, as I don't think these squares should appear in Windows Forms. you'll need to manually erase the transparent squares yourself (Don't use MS Paint, as that doesn't support transparency), or find a different texture with an actual transparent background.

Comment: I think you are creating the UI and when you insert (or attach) the image, it just shows those gray and white squares. Try running the UI and see if you still see those squares.

Comment: This might be the solution which can help you out: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416934/c-how-to-make-a-picture-background-transparent)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please write question titles that describe the problem. People want to know what question you have, not how long you're programming or what project you do. I changed it now for you.

Comment: @Myst: The link suggests that picturebox can't properly display a png with transparency. Not sure if that was true 20 years ago but it certainly is not true today. The answer ought o be deleted or at least maeked as outdated.

Answer (score 1):

- First make your button background color transparent and add your image.
- After that `Flatstyle = flat`

[image: Button Settings]

[image: Example]