# Make a transparent and movable pictureBox in windows forms app

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I used this tutorial to create a transparent picture box:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25048/How-to-Use-Transparent-Images-and-Labels-in-Window

However the issue is when I move the Object it also moves the background, so for example if it starts as this:
[image: Original position]

The transparent object is the image in the top left.

Then if I move the image it looks like this:

[image: Second position of transparent image]

It seems to drag the background with it.

The one thing I have figured out so far is that if the image is moved to the edge of the form then the background resets.

I assume this is because the `OnPaint` function is not run when the image is moved. but i tried manually running the function and it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: You're probably not invalidating the Parent. See the translucent Custom Control in the example here: [Translucent circular Control with text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51435842/7444103), note the `OnMouseDown()`, `OnMouseMove()` overrides and the `InvalidateParent()` method. Try to add that Control to a Form and drag it around at run-time (note that double-buffering is not exactly your friend here) -- I haven't actually checked the code you linked, but it's quite probably the issue (a relatively *subtle* one, I'm not sure it can be *cured* with a couple of method calls).

Comment: If you haven't noticed, you don't need to add any code to move that Control at run-time, it does it by itself, just click on it and drag it.

Comment: Could you show your current code?  Maybe you could refer tio [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19910172)