# Positioning a image onto another

Tags: c#, image-processing, overlay, webcam

I want to develop a program (in C#) that has following needs:

1. I want a webcam to take a image and display it on a picturebox (THIS I CAN DO)
2. Now i have a set of other images with me and i want to drag and drop these images on the clicked image and position them right with the mouse. Is it possible to put that photoshop functionality where you drag and position a picture over another and when you click save that becomes one single picture.It is more like i have a background image and i want to exactly position another image(s) onto the background image using the drag and drop functionality  Any answers are most appreciated. Thanking you guys in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Well for 2 question, i am sure you have to first understand the image format and closely work with the image rendering libraries. And then see how you can merge the 2 images files using that library. No direct solution. But yes its possible. May be search for some jpeg c# libraries to kick start.

Answer (score 0):

The code in the following links may help you:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressvcs/thread/360629bb-633c-4eeb-92a4-0af75de893fd/

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?t=378090

[A PictureBox Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem)