# Show multiple images in one picturebox

Tags: c#, picturebox

I am still very new to **C#** and I'm developing an application that holds all of my `textures` which are in a `png` format.

I am at a stage where I need to be able to show multiple `textures` within 1 `picture box`, could I ask how this is achieved?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14397404/overlay-two-or-more-bitmaps-to-show-in-picturebox-c Some thing Like this.??

Answer (score 1):

you can do it by making array of images you want to show.
Consider this [example](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/73eb92cb-7e33-4de9-bf52-4bf5314f6cda/Displaying%20an%20array%20of%20images%20in%20pictureBox%20C) and [tutorial](http://www.letsdevelopit.com/2009/04/picturebox-with-multiple-images-in-c.html) here to learn about it.

Comment: Many thanks for the response it has certainly helped me go in the correct direction!, I'm finding C# both facinating and a challenge and have also ordered a book on the subject to increase my knowledge.