# Perform Paint in top of multiple controls

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, paint, paintevent

I have a short problem.
How can i paint this kind of image in top of any `controls` like `textbox` etc.

This is my code:

```
Private Sub GroupBox6_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles GroupBox6.Paint
    If txtStatus.Text = "Cancelled" Then
        Try
            Dim newImage As Image = Image.FromFile(FOLDER_PATH & "\completed.png")
            Dim x As Single = ((GroupBox6.Width / 2) - (463 / 4))
            Dim y As Single = 10
            Dim width As Single = 463 / 2
            Dim height As Single = 242 / 2
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(newImage, x, y, width, height)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
     End If
End Sub
```

And this is my Output:

[image]

so my goal is to paint the image `Completed` in top of `textbox, label` inside my `groupbox` any idea?

Comment: Do you want to show the image as an overlay when the user has completed a process and hide the underlying controls? I think it's easier to use a PictureBox control that is shown instead of the Groupbox when the status is "Cancelled" instead of drawing the image on the groupbox.

Comment: @Markus if i use picture box it is not transparent that's why i paint the image on the control that will hold it. but in my case txtbox and label is covering the image. i just want to paint it and maybe send it to front of gropbox and other control inside of groupbox

Comment: There are two solutions that i can think of. 1. Create a layered window and show it on top of the controls 2. Take a screenshot of the part the image will appear and draw it on picbox and then draw the png image

Comment: @γηράσκωδ'αείπολλάδιδασκόμε hmm. can you give me a sample code or idea on how to do it. I think step 2 will work.

Comment: You should be able to get it working with a picturebox with a transparent PNG and some tweaking. Other methods that draw on the screen directly are quite flawed, because you don't own the screen. Check this out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4144371/a-picturebox-problem difficult to help more w/o a reproducing code.

Comment: @SimonMourier *Other methods that draw on the screen **directly**...* where did you see a method like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need two `bitmaps` and a `picturebox` for this to work. The first one is the `png` image and the second one the `picturebox` image:

```
Private pngImage, picBoxImage As Image
```

In form load event initialize the two images:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    pngImage = Image.FromFile(FOLDER_PATH & "\completed.png") //load it once
    picBoxImage = CType(pngImage.Clone, Image)

    PictureBox1.Size = New Size(CInt(463 / 2), CInt(242 / 2))
    PictureBox1.Parent = GroupBox6
    PictureBox1.Image = picBoxImage
    PictureBox1.Visible = False //you dont want it at the beggining
End Sub
```

The *sub* to show the picturebox:

```
Private Sub ShowCompletedMessage()
    Dim screenLocation As Point
    Dim gr As Graphics
    //you can pass these values as parameters in the sub if you want to make the code more generic
    Dim x As Integer = CInt(((GroupBox6.Width / 2) - (463 / 4)))
    Dim y As Integer = 10
    Dim width As Integer = CInt(463 / 2)
    Dim height As Integer = CInt(242 / 2)

    //Ensure that picturebox is not visible. If it is you don't need to take a screenshot
    If PictureBox1.Visible = True Then
        Return
    End If

    gr = Graphics.FromImage(picBoxImage)

    //you need to transform the coordinates to screen ones
    screenLocation = GroupBox6.PointToScreen(New Point(x, y))

    //draw the portion of the screen to your bitmap
    gr.CopyFromScreen(screenLocation.X, screenLocation.Y, 0, 0, New Size(width, height), CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy)

    //draw the png image on top
    gr.DrawImage(pngImage, 0, 0, width, height)

    PictureBox1.Location = New Point(x, y)
    PictureBox1.BringToFront()
    PictureBox1.Visible = True

    gr.Dispose()
    gr = Nothing


    Return

End Sub
```

Every time you want to show the message call the above sub. You decide from where and when. You need to hide `picturebox` if you don't need it anymore

```
PictureBox1.Visible = False
```

Comment: where should i put this kind of code in my form? inside groupbox paint event? so that i can try it and see the result

Comment: @Muj Do *width*, *height* and *position* of png image change? Of course position will be relative to *GroupBox6*.

Comment: yeah but where should i insert this code so that the system will execute it? in the `groupbox6 paint event?` or some where else?