# True Transparent Picturebox in VS2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, transparency, picturebox

In my WinForm Application, I am needing to layer some images. However, I'm having trouble getting a transparent control to place the image in.  I have done some research and came up with the following class:

```
public class TransparentPicture : PictureBox
{
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        // do nothing
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }

}
```

This seems to work fine until I close Visual Studios and reopen the Solution.  Then my controls all disappear in the designer.  They show when I run the program, but I need them to show in designer too where I can continue to design my application.

I know this isn't everything I need to do, because these controls are always causing my program to freeze up for a few seconds and stuff.

So my question is..does anybody know where I can find code for a transparent control, or how to fix the one I've thrown together?

Comment: WinForms doesn't really support true transparency.  Use WPF.

Comment: You can check if you're on DesignMode via code, and not run the `|= 0x20`, and run the `base.OnPaintBackground`, etc, if you are.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Picturebox transparent background doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: PictureBox already supports transparency without any special hacks.  Just set the BackColor to Color.Transparent.  Check the previous link for a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Make the TransparentPicture be a regular PictureBox, until an IsTransparent property is set to true.

Set the property to false on design time, and to true in FormLoad event (which will only happen when you actually run the application).

That way, on design time, they will behave as regular picture boxes, but when you run the application, they will become transparent.

```
public class TransparentPicture : PictureBox
{
    public bool IsTransparent { get; set; }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

            if (this.IsTransparent)
            {
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            }

            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsTransparent)
        {
            base.OnPaintBackground(e);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsTransparent)
        {
            RecreateHandle();
        }
        else
        {
            base.OnMove(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Then, on your FormLoad event, you should do:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.Controls.Count; i++)
{
    var tp = this.Controls[i] as TransparentPicture;

    if (tp != null)
    {
        tp.IsTransparent = true;
    }
}
```

Or if you only have a few:

```
tp1.IsTransparent = tp2.IsTransparent = tp3.IsTransparent = true;
```