# Overlapping PicuresBox with transparent background

Tags: c#, winforms, image, picturebox

I want make two or more overlapping `PictureBox` with transparent background but if I do this I see only one Image:

[image]

I create my `PictureBox`es like this:

```
PictureBox pb1 = new PictureBox();
pb1.Size = new Size(32, 32);
pb1.Location = new Point(0,0);
pb1.Image = Image.FromFile("../Graphics/Grounds/ground.png");
pb1.Visible = true;

PictureBox pb2 = new PictureBox();
pb2.Size = new Size(32, 32);
pb2.Location = new Point(0,0);
pb2.Image = Image.FromFile("../Graphics/Grounds/human.png");
pb2.Visible = true;
```

Later I add those two `PictureBox`es to my `Panel`:

```
panel1.Controls.Add(pb1);
panel1.Controls.Add(pb2);
```

So why does it only shows one `PictureBox`?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9158849/838405

Answer (score 0):

Try change `panel1.Controls.Add(pb2);` to `pb1.Controls.Add(pb2);`
Make sure you set the correct location as `pb1` be the container

Answer (score -1):

If your human.png has transparent background:

```
pb2.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

Comment: no, the main problem here is that the human picturebox should be inserted as a groundPicBox's subControl, as reported here http://stackoverflow.com/a/9158849/838405 and on Hans Passant answer