# How to remove white background color from Bitmap

Tags: c#, image, background, bitmap, picturebox

I want to remove the white background color in a bitmap

```
Bitmap capcha = new Bitmap("C:/image.jpg");
pictureBox1.Image = capcha;
```

but I want to display in my pictureBox1 just the image without white that exists in the background

Comment: You do know that 32bit PNG supports transparent background, yes?

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I treat a jpg not png :)

Comment: @spender is right, use .PNG instead of .JPG, refer [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try to set transparency in capcha like this:

```
Bitmap capcha = new Bitmap(@"C:/image.jpg");
capcha.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
pictureBox1.Image = capcha;
```

I hope it is what u need.

Comment: That'll give strange results on JPEG though, since it's full of compression artifacts that will be "not-quite-exactly-white" instead of "white".

Comment: You are right, but question was 'how to remove white background'. You should avoid those 'not-quite-exactly-white' pixels or find other way.

Comment: The problematic part here is of course, "white background"; the background on jpeg is _never_ just 'white', but you can assume they'll still want to remove _all_ of it.

Comment: Apparently you are able to create .jpg image that has no intermediate pixels. You just need to adjust quality of your image (simple sample https://imgur.com/X4cQ1aZ)

Comment: Gimp's "select by color" function set to zero-tolerance disagrees with you. Still plenty of rogue pixels in there, even on 100% quality. https://i.imgur.com/f45Sgeg.png

Comment: It depends on you needs. For me several rogue pixels, even if exists is not a problem. It would be better if you propose other solution than complain about one which appears that fits (taking into account upvotes).

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to criticise; I was just making a remark that the use of the jpeg format complicates this operation.