# Color surounded in other colors? (Borderless form, Picture box, Transparency Key)

Tags: c#, image, visual-studio, picturebox

So I am aiming to make a picture box have an image in it, that is covered in a transparent background, But when I put it in the Picture box that is on my form and set the transparency key to 240, 240, 240 (This is the color transparent shows up in on the Picture box) Most of it works fine but it produces a picture like this: https://gyazo.com/7f28b2a920d3af90c0c98cc37fedab3d. I am aiming for it to just look like what is in the picture but without the white around it, Thanks an advance for anyone willing to answer me.

Comment: Remove the anti-aliased pixels! - Duplicate of [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39822808/c-sharp-transparency-key-not-working-correctly/39867248?s=2|0.6108#39867248)

Comment: Would love to do that but that makes the picture extremely rough, Is there a way around this?

Comment: No. That's the only way, at least with one winforms form.

Comment: Well what about a WPF Form?

Comment: I don't do wpf but it fully supports transparency, so there chances are much better..