# How to make it so my picturebox[that can move] overlap the picturebox it should move over?

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

and today I was testing my game, and wondering how to make it so when you move over a ladder (you control the picturebox1 with arrows keys, and the ladder is picturebox2) the player moves over the ladder, like, when you move on the bounds of the ladder, you go "under" the ladder and I want to make it so that you go "over" the ladder. Here is a picture of going under the ladder: [image: Picture of the form]

Is this even possible? Also, i am looking to do this within the code, thanks for your time! 
Note: The player is the red cube

Comment: Please check [the previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work.). Especially the answer of @trippino.

Answer (score 0):

Very Simple. try this

```
PictureBox Ladder = new PictureBox();
...setting the picture and it's location...
PictureBox Player = new PictureBox();
...setting the picture and it's location...
Ladder.SendToBack();
or...
Player.BringToFront();
```

The player control will be drawn before the ladder.