# Drawing transparent pixels in pictureBox C#

Tags: c#, winforms, image

I have a picture box, and import a .png picture into.
Now when I rotate the actual image, the "free" space of the picture box, that does not include the image is filled by black pixels.

**Q:** How to make that black pixels transparent?

**Edit:**

Here is the rotation code

```
public static Bitmap RotateImage(Image image, PointF offset, float angle)
        {
            if (image == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            try
            {
                Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
                rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp))
                {
                    g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
                    g.RotateTransform(angle);
                    g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
                    g.DrawImage(image, new Point(0, 0));
                }
                return rotatedBmp;
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryException)
            {
                GC.Collect();
            }
            catch (ArgumentException)
            {

            }
            return image as Bitmap;
        }
```

**Here are original and modified images:**

[image: Original image]

[image: Rotated image with black pixels]

Comment: Background color in the PictureBox instead?  Or are you saying this "free" space is the image?

Comment: Like when you rotate the actual image in the picture box let's say 45 angle, that means that you have small triangles on opposite corners left free (without image). That triangles are rendered with black pixels.

Comment: If this seems to appear only after rotating, then you might want to show us that code in case it's that operation that is at fault.

Comment: `pictureBox1.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent`?

Comment: Reference:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: @DonBoitnott Yes, it is set

Comment: This question is *very* poorly documented, we can't see how the PNG specifies the transparency and whether the code that rotates the images ensures that no color shifts occur.  Post a link to the image file and a snippet that shows code.

Comment: What framework do u use and how do u import the image to the the picturebox ?

Comment: VS2012->DevExpress, I import it from DB.

Answer (score 0):

PictureBox supports transparency if you set the `SupportsTransparentBackColor` property of `System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles` to true, put this in your Form_Load.

```
this.SetStyle(System.Windows.Forms.ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

You can set `BackColor` on the PictureBox to another colour if you wish, by default it will be `DefaultBackColor`.

Comment: I put back color transparent, but it didn't help

Comment: Did you set the ControlStyles? I have updated with a code sample.

Comment: My pic box is on another control, so when I try to write that code, using picturebox1 instead of this, it says that cannot access set style as it is protected

Comment: It's obviously PictureEdit (DevEX), but it makes no sense

Comment: What if you set this on your Form rather than the parent control?