# Clear drawn rectangle on picturebox to show movement

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I try to simulate trains movement in my application ,so i create trains map using this code :

```
 public void DrawMap()
        {
            Bitmap map = new Bitmap(pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Width, pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Height);
            var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);
            List<Point> lstPointLeft = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var t in lstSensorLeft)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation, t.YLocation);
                lstPointLeft.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation, t.YLocation, 3, 3);
                try
                {
                    graph.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                }
                catch (Exception ea)
                {

                }
                if (t.StationId != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectEhsansq = new Rectangle(t.XLocation - 6, t.YLocation - 6, 12, 12);
                    graph.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectEhsansq);
                    Label ObjLable = new Label();
                    ObjLable.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                    ObjLable.Location = new Point(t.XLocation+40, t.YLocation +50);
                    ObjLable.Text = ObjStationRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.StationId).First().Name;
                    ObjLable.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    ObjLable.Width = 70;
                    pictureBoxMetroMap.Controls.Add(ObjLable);

                }
            }

            List<Point> lstPointRight = new List<Point>();

            foreach (var t in lstSensorRight)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30);
                lstPointRight.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30, 3, 3);
                graph.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                if (t.StationId != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectPosition = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 24, t.YLocation + 24, 12, 12);
                    graph.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectPosition);

                    Label ObjLable = new Label();
                    ObjLable.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
                    ObjLable.Location = new Point(t.XLocation - 50, t.YLocation - 30);
                    ObjLable.Text = ObjStationRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.StationId).First().Name;
                    ObjLable.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    ObjLable.Width = 70;
                    pictureBoxMetroMap.Controls.Add(ObjLable);

                }
            }

            graph.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointLeft.ToArray());
            graph.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointRight.ToArray());
            pictureBoxMetroMap.Image = map;

           // ShowOnlineTrain();
            //Thread newThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ShowOnlineTrain));

            //newThread.Start();

        }
```

So as you can see the **DramMap** draws my trains map ,i call this function in **page_load** of my application as you can see here :

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateListBox = new UpdateListBoxDelegate(this.UpdateStatus);
        // Initialise and start worker thread
        workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ShowOnlineTrain));
        workerThread.Start();
        DrawMap();
    }
```

So as you can see above i call my function and i create a thread in my **pageload**, so the thread do a vital operation ,it calls a function **ShowOnlineTrain** ,this function fetch the locations of online trains and i should show these trains on my map :

```
List<OnlineTrain> OnlineTrainList = new List<OnlineTrain>();
        public void ShowOnlineTrain()
        {

            OnlineTrainRepository objOnlineTrainRepository = new OnlineTrainRepository();


           while(true)
            {
                OnlineTrainList = objOnlineTrainRepository.GetAll().ToList();

                    Invoke(UpdateListBox);

            }



           }
  private void UpdateStatus()
        {
            lstLog.Items.Add("Train Id=" + OnlineTrainList.First().TrainId + " | Current x position=" + OnlineTrainList.First().XTrainLocation + " | Current y position=" + OnlineTrainList.First().YTrainLocation);

        }
```

This function fetches the location of online trains .so **OnlineTrainList ** has the locations of online trains (i.e x and y and trainId).so i have to show the trains on my map .I call the **Paint** event of my picturebox :

```
  private void pictureBoxMetroMap_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (OnlineTrainList.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (OnlineTrain t in OnlineTrainList)
                {
                    var g = pictureBoxMetroMap.CreateGraphics();
                    Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             t.YTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             7, 7);
                    g.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);
                }

            }
        }
```

It gets all positions of **OnlineTrainList ** and draws them ,but i have a big problem here ,i need to show the movement of my train ,i should clear the old location of my train ,but i don't know how can i do that??? and all positions of my trains is drawn on my picturebox !!any idea ?

Best regards

Comment: Side note:  do not use `CreateGraphics` in the `Paint` handler.  You get that for free using `e.Graphics`.

Comment: @DonBoitnott the answer that you posted it works ,but it clears whole map ,i need to clear the trains on the map

Comment: What is "map"?  Is it the image that is loaded and assigned to `PictureBox.Image`?  Or is it what is being drawn onto the `PictureBox` in code?

Comment: @DonBoitnott yes exactly the map is the image that is assigned to pb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you create 2 same sized `PictureBoxes`: another one for the map and another over it for the trains, using transparency on the top one. Since they are the same size, the locations match, too: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158849/2538037

When the form has loaded, you start a `BackgroundWorker`, which updates trains and locations to the top `PictureBox` via `ProgressChanged`-event. You could use it to draw the image and then set it to the top `PictureBox`. You could use some timing on it, so it would calculate a new updated train-image like every 2 seconds. You should also use `Dispose()` to the old image after changing in the new one. Remember to use `Invalidate()` so the PictureBoxes are updated.

Comment: I want to try your method ,but how can i the map two pictureboxs?

Comment: I think it works, but you wanted to clear the trains on the map, therefore you need to separate the trains and map image. I provided the link above about how to use those 2 pictureboxes. Use the designer to drop another `PictureBox` over the old one, and check that the sizes match.

Comment: It works great ,but in background image i had some labels ,when i put the train picturebox on it ,they disappear!!!why ?You can see my labels  in DrawMap function

Comment: Try adding the labels to the new upper PictureBox instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you have assigned an image to the `PictureBox` using `pictureBoxMetroMap.Image =`, then you should be able to draw onto the `PictureBox` surface without disturbing that image.

Now, if you are then drawing additional "map" graphics manually, then you must continue to do so on every `Paint` cycle.  Meaning that `Paint` must handle redrawing the "map" detail, *as well as* refreshing the train graphics to simulate movement.

Make sure that the code responsible for recognize or recording train movement data is calling `pictureBoxMetroMap.Invalidate();` to trigger `Paint` calls.

Comment: it works ,but it clears whole map ,i need to clear the trains on the map

Comment: So don't you think that using panel instead of pb have the same problem (it clears whole map ,i need to clear the trains on the map )

Comment: I have to use pb ,because my map scale is so big ,and i need scroll ,and the panel doesn't have this scroll