# Drawn shape in Picturebox doesn't clear

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am trying to show a train that moves on the map .so let me explain my method ,i draw my map on  Picturebox **Map**,and my trains on another picturebox **train**,i put the **Train** PictureBox on **map** picturebox .

More details:https://stackoverflow.com/a/9158849/2538037

So i use two function here :

```
 public void DrawMap()
        {

            var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);
            List<Point> lstPointLeft = new List<Point>();
            foreach (var t in lstSensorLeft)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation, t.YLocation);
                lstPointLeft.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation, t.YLocation, 3, 3);
                try
                {
                    graph.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                }
                catch (Exception ea)
                {

                }
                if (t.StationId != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectEhsansq = new Rectangle(t.XLocation - 6, t.YLocation - 6, 12, 12);
                    graph.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectEhsansq);

                    graph.DrawString(ObjStationRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.StationId).First().Name, pictureBoxMetroMap.Font, Brushes.White, t.XLocation +40, t.YLocation +50);

                }
            }

            List<Point> lstPointRight = new List<Point>();

            foreach (var t in lstSensorRight)
            {
                Point objPoint = new Point(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30);
                lstPointRight.Add(objPoint);
                Rectangle rectSens = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 30, t.YLocation + 30, 3, 3);
                graph.FillRectangle(whiteBrush, rectSens);
                if (t.StationId != null)
                {
                    Rectangle rectPosition = new Rectangle(t.XLocation + 24, t.YLocation + 24, 12, 12);
                    graph.FillRectangle(blueBrush, rectPosition);

                    graph.DrawString(ObjStationRepository.FindBy(i => i.Id == t.StationId).First().Name, pictureBoxMetroMap.Font, Brushes.White, t.XLocation - 50, t.YLocation - 30);
                }
            }

            graph.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointLeft.ToArray());
            graph.DrawLines(pLine, lstPointRight.ToArray());
            pictureBoxMetroMap.Image = map;


        }
```

This function draws map ,and this function draws my trains on another picturebox:

```
 public void DrawOnlineTrain()
        {
            var graph = Graphics.FromImage(map);

            if (OnlineTrainList.Count > 0)
            {

                foreach (OnlineTrain t in OnlineTrainList.ToList())
                {
                   // graph.Dispose();
                    Rectangle rectTrainState = new Rectangle(t.XTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             t.YTrainLocation.Value - 3,
                                                             7, 7);
                    graph.FillRectangle(RedBrush, rectTrainState);
                }
            }
            pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = map;



    }
```

So i use a thread to update the **Train** picturebox ,i call  the thread in form_load :

```
 private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            pictureBoxonlineTrain.Parent = pictureBoxMetroMap;
            map= new Bitmap(pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Width, pictureBoxMetroMap.Size.Height);
            UpdateListBox = new UpdateListBoxDelegate(this.UpdateStatus);
            // Initialise and start worker thread
            workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.GetOnlineTrain));
            workerThread.Start();
}
```

So in the thread i start a method that gets the location of online train:

```
  public void GetOnlineTrain()
        {        
           while(true)
            {
                OnlineTrainRepository objOnlineTrainRepository = new OnlineTrainRepository();
                OnlineTrainList = objOnlineTrainRepository.GetAll().ToList();
                objOnlineTrainRepository = null;
                Invoke(UpdateListBox);

            }

        }
```

Here i start **UpdateListBox** that draw my **Train**:

```
 private void UpdateStatus()
        {

            foreach (OnlineTrain onlineTrain in OnlineTrainList.ToList())
            {

              lstLog.Items.Add("Train Id=" + onlineTrain.TrainId + " | Current x position=" + onlineTrain.XTrainLocation + " | Current y position=" + onlineTrain.YTrainLocation);
              pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = null;

                DrawOnlineTrain();
            }


        }
```

As you can see here to show movement i have to clear the old location of trains ,and i do that using :

```
pictureBoxonlineTrain.Image = null;
```

But it doesn't work ,and every rectangle is remain on my screen ?!!!

Best regards

Comment: Try pictureBoxonlineTrain.Refresh()

Comment: I used that but it doesn't work

Comment: try `this.Invalidate();` last line in `UpdateStatus();`

Comment: you are using one and the same `Bitmap map` for all drawing right?

Comment: @olydis yes I use the same Bitmap for both of them

Comment: @HassanNisar i did that .not working

Comment: that is an issue ;) answer in progress!

Comment: @olydis it just is used for finding the size of picturebox

Comment: @EA "it just is used for finding the size of picturebox" - and what about all those `Graphics.FromImage(map);`? You are drawing to it, and **only** to it - same instance you created back in `Load` ;-)

Comment: So if i create another instance of bitmap ,is it solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. To address your problem directly**

- you never clear the bitmap! Note that you are drawing **on top** of everything that is already there when using `Graphics.FromImage`
- you use one and the same `Bitmap` object for all drawing. So (in combination with the previous point) you basically have the entire "scene" in `map` all the time - no need to have several `PictureBox`es in that case!
- be careful: if a `PictureBox` refresehes **while** you're drawing, the unfinished state will be visible! You are manipulating the very image that is shown.

**2. What I would do**

- render everything to one buffer (you are using `Bitmap` which is fine, but maybe consider using `BufferedGraphics`)
- render that to a control whenever you like (or it's `Paint` event fires) **instead** of using a `PictureBox`