# How to change backcolor, with back object color?

Tags: c#, backcolor

When I move a picturebox in a form when application is started, I want *picturebox backcolor* with transparency using back object color, But no transparent with form *backcolor*

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to set the back color as same as the form which is solid color. U can user the Backcolor property of the picture box and set it to form's back color.

Also have a look at this post.

[C# Picturebox transparent background doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work)