# How to make picturebox transparent when it comes above another image

Tags: c#, picturebox, transparent

I am making an application in C#.NET with Visual Studio 2012.

I have a picture in my background form. I have several picture boxes on it. I used .png images with transparent background but in my form it is not transparent when it comes above another image.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Picturebox transparent background doesn't seem to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: Stacking doesn't work, you see the Parent, not the controls that you overlapped.  Don't overlap or layer by using the Paint event instead.

Answer (score 0):

Set your picture box back color property to transparent.

```
pictureBoxTest.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

To further explain, an image with a transparent background will inherit the picture box's background color. You need to set the color to transparent as well to ensure it truly is.

Comment: I didn't mark the doe vote, but an answer saying something duplicate is not a quality answer. You need to vote to close the question as duplicate.

Comment: @BlackFrog, thank you. I am very new so I wrote the answer and mentioned the duplicate. I then read how to correctly mark the duplicate post and flagged it too. I guess I should have edited the answer to remove the duplicate to people didn't downvote. Live and learn I guess.