# Back color changed to black while converting a bitmap to memorystream and then back to Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap, picturebox, memorystream

I face an issue. I am trying to convert the Bitmap image into a memoryStream and store it. When converting the memoryStream back to image the background is becoming black

```
ms = new MemoryStream();
frm.pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

as suggested above i tried `Graphics.Clear()` method to set the background Transparent. But no success. Still the background is black. Anyone please suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# Picturebox transparent background doesn't seem to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522337/c-sharp-picturebox-transparent-background-doesnt-seem-to-work)

Comment: What format does the Image have? What is the source? Does it contain Transparency? Also: There is not enough code shown!

Comment: From what we see(!) this doesn't look like a duplicate..

Comment: This should work: `MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
pictureBox1.Image.Save(ms, pictureBox1.Image.RawFormat);
pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);
ms.Dispose();`

Comment: @TaW Actually, [closing the stream is against specs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) and is known to cause issues. These can be avoided by creating a new Bitmap object from the one created from stream (using the `new Bitmap(bmp)` constructor), and then disposing both the image-from-stream and the stream while keeping the object created from the `new Bitmap(bmp)` constructor. (It has the slight disadvantage of converting the image to 32bpp, but if it's just for showing on UI that should be no problem)

Comment: On the question... you should show more code. What you show is making an image from a new, empty `MemoryStream`. That can never work. The stream should at least be initialized using a byte array.