# Draggable transparent windows/forms in c sharp

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, transparency, drag

I have used a png with transparent background in a C# form.
I followed the question at [Transparent images with C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-winforms) and its accepted answer does excatly what I want except the dragging part. I use a `Form` as the hosting control.

The problem is when I drag the control, it does not repaint the background, thus the transparency goes and the very first occuring background filling the control.

I tried using `Invalidate()` inside `OnMove` `override`. But it didn t work for me.

I think clearing the existing background and redrawing the image at drag would do what I want.

But how to achieve it?

Thank you for any help