# Control To Control Transparency

Tags: c#, winforms

So having trying for a while with no luck, i eventually decided to ask about a way to make a transparent controls display each others.

[image]

As you see in the picture i have 2 transparent picture boxes, they show the background very well but when it comes to the selected picturebox as you can see in the picture it only renders the background image of the form but not the other picture box below it. I know that there are a common circumstances in winforms due to the lack of proper rendering but the question is :

Is there a way to get around this rendering glitch, is there a way to make the transparent controls render each others ?

Well this is the Answer : [Transparent images with C# WinForms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-sharp-winforms/434706#434706)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The transparency of a control depends on its parent control .You can however, use a custom container control instead of a picture box for the parent image.and maybe this code is usfull

```
    using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class TransparentControl : Control
{
    private readonly Timer refresher;
    private Image _image;

    public TransparentControl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        refresher = new Timer();
        refresher.Tick += TimerOnTick;
        refresher.Interval = 50;
        refresher.Enabled = true;
        refresher.Start();
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }


    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_image != null)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, (Width / 2) - (_image.Width / 2), (Height / 2) - (_image.Height / 2));
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
       //Do not paint background
    }

    //Hack
    public void Redraw()
    {
        RecreateHandle();
    }

    private void TimerOnTick(object source, EventArgs e)
    {
        RecreateHandle();
        refresher.Stop();
    }

    public Image Image
    {
        get
        {
            return _image;
        }
        set
        {
            _image = value;
            RecreateHandle();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not give the expected result any other ideas ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11412169/is-it-possible-to-have-two-overlapping-picturebox-controls-with-transparent-imag

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-sharp-winforms/434706#434706