# Adding GIF Pictures with tranparent bg

Tags: c#, picturebox

I used [this control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/434706/726169) but it does not support GIF file format, as the picture does not move like in `PictureBox`.

Comment: You could convert your pictures from GIF to a format that is actually supported (PNG maybe?)

Comment: I want My Picture to animate!!! actually, this is a circle for loading, it orbits till something loads

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [`Bitmap.MakeTransparent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8517ckds) and [`ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/16z0hwkd.aspx) in `OnPaint` event for simple `PictureBox`:

```
private Image animGif;// gif animation file

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    animGif = new Bitmap("file.png");
    ImageAnimator.Animate(animGif, Animate);
}

private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames();
    var img = new Bitmap(animGif, animGif.Width, animGif.Height);
    img.MakeTransparent(Color.White);
    e.Graphics.Clear(pictureBox1.BackColor);
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(img, new Point(0, 0));
}

private void Animate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}
```

Comment: Are you used `ImageAnimator.Animate` too? I updated my answer