# Transparent background-image on Form

Tags: c#, winforms, image, background, transparency

I am creating a C# WinForms application with a transparent background and a transparent background image which is pasted in the form background. The background image is not displayed properly because it shows the green background of some parts of the image. When I show the image in the application's background without setting the TransparencyKey and BackColor, the image is displayed correctly.

```
BackColor = Color.LimeGreen;
TransparencyKey = Color.LimeGreen;
BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile(@"c:\Temp\cherries.png");
```

Please see the image:
[image: Picture vs winform application]

Comment: follow this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-sharp-winforms?rq=1

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I want to display transparent cherries in the transparent form application correctly.

Comment: You need a different transparency mode, per-pixel alpha blending.  It isn't directly supported by winforms because it is very incompatible with traditional GDI rendering in Windows which renders RGB with an alpha of 0.  So controls like TextBox are not visible.  It is the default mode for WPF, you can easily google winforms code with a "winforms per-pixel alpha" query.