# C# alpha image overlapping

Tags: c#, .net, custom-controls, transparency, gdi

I've created a transparent control as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-sharp-winforms)

```
public partial class TransparentControl : UserControl
{
    private readonly Timer refresher;
    private Image _image;

    public TransparentControl()
        {
            SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
            BackColor = Color.Transparent;
            refresher = new Timer();
            refresher.Tick += TimerOnTick;
            refresher.Interval = 50;
            refresher.Enabled = true;
            refresher.Start();
        }

        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
                cp.ExStyle |= 0x20;
                return cp;
            }
        }

        protected override void OnMove(EventArgs e)
        {
            RecreateHandle();
        }


        protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle((Width / 2) - (_image.Width / 2), (Height / 2) - (_image.Height / 2), _image.Width, _image.Height));
        }

        protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
        {}

        public void Redraw()
        {
            RecreateHandle();
        }

        private void TimerOnTick(object source, EventArgs e)
        {
            RecreateHandle();
            refresher.Stop();
        }

        public Image Image
        {
            get { _image; }
            set { _image = value; RecreateHandle(); }
        }
}
```

The problem is that if i overlap two TransparentControl object, the one that stays on top is not being rendered (or maybe it's being rendered but is not visible at all).
Is there something to add to the control to fix this?

Because using PictureBox for the top image works, but on Linux with Mono its not rendering alpha pixels. That's why I need to use this TransparentControl.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I presume this is Winforms? Transparency in GDI is a hack where it just draws the color underneath the control

Comment: Yes is Winforms. But lets i got a circle to draw on a square. Both got different colors. It should render them correctly. Instead i only see the square

Comment: Its a little hard to distinguish the problem in the code here but its possible that there is a refresh between the drawing of both controls

Comment: Yes there's a refresh timer in both controls

Comment: If you want quality looking controls in winforms its better to draw everything yourself via paint. Works great there

Comment: But I'm actually using OnPaint method, then calling DrawImage in it. It's not working.