# adding picture to moving pictureBoxes

Tags: c#

I am developing a game, where we have a spaceship, rockets, and some picture boxes showing the enemy. The goal is to kill the enemy with rockets.

I  used this code for the picture boxes but this won't make a good result.

```
foreach (Control element in ptb_backGround.Controls)
{
    if (element is PictureBox && element.Name != "ptb_spaceShip")
    {
        Image enimisPic = Properties.Resources.Alien_displeased_icon;
        element.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        ptb_backGround.Controls.Add(element);
        element.BackgroundImage = enimisPic;
        element.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
    }
}
```

Screenshot, with a placeholder / rectangle
[image]

Screenshot, with the actual image
[image]

Comment: I think using of sprites (DirectX) or other 2D/3D engines would be good for gaming https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsmobile.directx.direct3d.sprite(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395256/transparent-images-with-c-sharp-winforms/434706#434706

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem once too and i tried many solutions, They al worked form me but the did flicker when moving.
except this with
this [control](http://www.codeproject.com/script/Articles/ArticleVersion.aspx?aid=26878&av=611298).

But I would not use forms is not suitable for making games. I would use XNA or Unity if I were you

I hope I have solved your problem